# C# Generic parameters - is there any "nullable or not" constraint

Tags: c#, nullable, generic-constraints

I'm often building tools with generics and **Expression<Func<object, value>>** to target properties of the object.
I keep struggling on a very stupid limitation of C# (but maybe I am ignorant of the proper solution).

Let's say we have this object:

```
class MyObject {
  public int NeverNull { get; set; }
  public int? CanBeNull { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
int? val1 = Foo(o => o.NeverNull);
int? val2 = Foo(o => o.CanBeNull);
```

I have 2 solutions to do this :

```
// Solution 1: two overloads
// First overload: for the non-nullable properties
TValue? Foo<TValue>(Expression<Func<MyObject, TValue>> selector)
  where TValue: struct
{ ... }

// Second overload: for the nullable properties
TValue? Foo<TValue>(Expression<Func<MyObject, TValue?>> selector)
  where TValue: struct
{ ... }
```

And

```
// Solution 2: using object
TValue? Foo<TValue>(Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> selector)
  where TValue: struct
{ ... }
```

The first solution implies doubling the logic, which is meh.
The second solution implies weak-typing issues and useless boxing/unboxing.

Is there a third, cleaner solution to have a 'nullable-or-not' generic parameter ?

Comment: Does it need to be constrained to value types? Is there a reason you need any constraints at all? An unconstrained generic method will take any nullable or non-nullable value type. For solution 1, you could forward both `Foo`s to a private, unconstrained generic method to avoid duplication of logic.

Comment: Good comment, you pointed an issue in the question. I updated the question => I always need the function to return the nullable version of the related property, whether it's nullable or not. (I won't explain why, that would be off-topic)

Comment: Both `NeverNull` and `CanBeNull` can be used with the `Expression<Func<MyObject, TValue?>>` version. You just have to accept that type inference won't work for `NeverNull`.